# Add a information about PK value to the output message - easier to find the flawed record

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm an assistant data manager and we process thousands of records of data every day.. I keep going blind trying to find the one field that has, for example a date conversion error, and I search and search. Sometimes its obvious and an easy fix but often it isn't.

We have one table 'original' where raw data is input. We then use stored proceedures of code to process and query the data while moving it into either 'validate' or 'stored'. If there are error the data is moved to 'validate' and if there are no errors then those data records are moved to 'stored.

When the data is moved and the data which fails the logic statements which we code, those generate error logs per failure. I try to do this in batches of 10 to keep the record numbers low, but within each record there can be upto 100 fields to check. That is 1,000 individual fields to check for date time error or real decimal errors, the most common error type.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If the above is an example of a run-time error vs my written coded logic 'if else' errors then how do I get it to pass along the primary key value so that I know which row it is out of say 10 rows of hundreds of fields to check is the row with the error.

I keep going blind during error checking and correcting data .. how do I improve the error message above? I'd love the above error message be able to output and say PK = 000100 .. so:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   PK = 000100

Is there any way to do this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.2 program and we are running SQL Server 2016.

Thanks.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to do this.

Comment: *"I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v 17.2"* isn't a version of SQL Server, that's a version of SSMS (an application used to interact with SQL Server). If you're using SQL Server 2012+, then you do have access to `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST`, if you're performing explicit conversions. If you're performing implicit conversions, then I'd start looking at those columns.

Comment: That is not a "compiler" error - it is a run-time error. If you have frequent errors of this type, it may make more sense to change the process you use to "process thousands of records" to something that supports logging (in some fashion) rows that have errors.

Comment: So how exactly are you processing these records, that's probably the key to how this gets fixed?  One trick I used to use for large data sets with one bad date was loading the data into Excel, changing the format of the problem column to DATE, then filtering for errors.  If your data is coming from text files then you could pre-validate it in your application, but what are you actually using to load this data?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with more info. Server 2016 and what we do with the records from the 'original' table where all the raw data is input, this is then processed into two further tables 'validate' and 'stored'. All done within SQL Server 2016.  Only records which have errors are sent to 'validate' with matched error logs for every single logic fail .. I'd like the run-time errors as above to include the PK .. so I know the specific data record to review. Is this possible?

Thanks for teaching me it was a run-time error vs compiler error. I'm relearning SQL fast!

Comment: Yes, you can do this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you ***can*** do this but you have to ask the right question.

Question:
Can I intercept the PK row when SQL server spits out the error?

Answer:
Well, yes, but only for the one append query and if it was one row.

Real answer:
Well, then use a append query for each single row, and you can thus get and grab the PK and this gives your required information.

Assuming I have this append:

```
INSERT INTO TimeTest
     (CustomerNames, StartTime, EndTime, StartTimeT, EndTimeT, StartTimeD)
SELECT
     CustomerNames, StartTime, EndTime, StartTimeT, EndTimeT, StartTimeD
FROM  MySource
```

In above , the target table (TimeTest) has strong typed date + time columns.

The source table (MySource) has every column as a text type (some kind of character) column.  This data was the result of a import. So there can and will be columns of data that are bad and incorrect date columns.

So, when  run the above, I get this:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type 
resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Now, of course, I want the PK of above. So, I suggest using a cursor. With a cursor, I can grab the PK before I append the one row.

in fact, I would also code in a list of decimal, and date columns and have the code ***when*** a conversion error occurs also spit out the actual column name.

I would also suggest you build some kind of front end (say in Access, or vb.net etc.) that can then display + process these bad records. That user system should also have the ability to remember fixes and edits.
And a edit + save would send this fixed row right into the server table (that final resting table).

Anyway, here is a stored procedure that will do this:

```
Create PROCEDURE MyInsertTrap
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PKID int
DECLARE @MyCol as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @MyErr as nvarchar(200)

set nocount on

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT        id 
FROM          MySource

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @pkid 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   

       BEGIN TRY
       INSERT INTO TimeTest
              (CustomerNames, StartTime, EndTime, StartTimeT, EndTimeT, StartTimeD)
        SELECT
              CustomerNames, StartTime, EndTime, StartTimeT, EndTimeT, StartTimeD
        FROM MySource where MySource.id = @pkid;

       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
          -- Error in append, show pk, + error
          PRINT 'ERROR IN APPEND FOR PK = ' + cast( @pkid as nvarchar(10))
          PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()

       END CATCH

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @pkid 
    END
    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
```

output from above:

```
 ERROR IN APPEND FOR PK = 14522
 The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type 
 resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Note that we could append this bad record to some other fixing table. And we could even do additional processing.

So, if we use a row by row "cursor" processing, we not only trap the one line that fails to append, but we can even start to add code that would spit out the actual column that failed, and even send the records to some desktop program that would allow humans to edit + see each record, correct and tap a button to then send the record off to the final table.

With this code, then the append query ***does not*** stop on a bad row, but keeps going for all of the records. The output ***will only*** show failed rows, but the valid rows will get past this error trapping.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining and showing details. I'll be applying this with my colleagues help so that our error checking so that we know the exact PK and field column. This is going to speed us up quite a bit. Cheers.

Ps. you're absolutely right about knowing how to ask the question, the problem is when you've a set amount of knowledge and don't know what you don't know in order to phrase the question to get to the answer you want. Fortunately you understood my goal.